# how to CheckALL with Ember.js checkBox

Tags: ember.js

could  someone give me a sample?

```
{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="isAllChecked"}}

{{view Ember.Checkbox }}

{{view Ember.Checkbox }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/G2Hrz/

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    isDog: false,
    isCat: false,
    isLion: false,
    isAll: function(_, value) {        
        if (arguments.length == 2) {
            this.set("isDog", value);
            this.set("isCat", value);
            this.set("isLion", value);
        } 
        return this.get("isDog") && this.get("isCat") && this.get("isLion");
    }.property("isDog", "isCat", "isLion")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if this is what you want, but here is a try: http://jsbin.com/ekoyiw/8/edit

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  checkedOne: false,
  checkedTwo: false,
  checkedThree: false,
  isAllChecked: false,
  checkAll: function() {
    var isAll = this.get('isAllChecked');
    this.setProperties({checkedOne: isAll, checkedTwo: isAll, checkedThree: isAll});
  }.observes('isAllChecked')
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate thru child views and make each item checked. For Ember 1.11 or higher.

Imagine you have a similar setup:

```
{{ input type='checkbox' checked=isAllChecked }}
{{#each message in model}}
    {{#component 'message-row' tagName='div' as |component|}}
        {{ input type='checkbox' checked=component.isChecked }}
    {{/component}}
{{/each}}
```

First checkbox outside the #each block sets whether all items will be checked or not.

```
checkAll: function() {
    var isAllChecked = this.get('controller.isAllChecked');
    this.get('childViews').filterBy('tagName', 'div').forEach(function(row) {
        row.set('isChecked', isAllChecked);
    });
}.observes('controller.isAllChecked')
```

We observe it against any changes, if any occurs checkAll is triggered, where it finds all child views, filters only the tags we need (div's in this case, since each checkbox is wrapped in a div), iterates them and set isChecked=true.

Since childViews is only accessible from view, code above should reside in the view class, not controller.